# How to Superimpose Multiple Density Curves Into One Plot in R

Tags: r, statistics, plot

I have a data that looks like [this](http://dpaste.com/88561/plain/).

And I intend to create multiple density curve into one plot, where each curve
correspond to the unique ID.

I tried to use "sm" package, with this code, but without success.

```
library(sm)
dat <- read.table("mydat.txt");
plotfn <- ("~/Desktop/flowgram_superimposed.pdf");
pdf(plotfn);

sm.density.compare(dat$V1,dat$V2, xlab = "Flow Signal")
colfill <- c(2:10);
legend(locator(1), levels(dat$V2), fill=colfill)

dev.off();
```

Please advice what's the right way to do it or if  there is
alternative way to do it?

I am trying to get this kind of plot  at the end. 
[figure http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/2736/testl.png](http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/2736/testl.png)

Comment: Asking questions here _and_ in the R-list at the same time: Not cool. http://www.nabble.com/Howto-Superimpose-Multiple-Density-Curves-Into-One-Plot-td25254899.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why, considering that there isn't yet a great deal of overlap between the two groups of users.  Can you elaborate on why that shouldn't be done?

Comment: "Multi-posting is a waste of bandwidth, money, and people's time, with no advantages whatever, and should never be indulged in." http://bit.ly/Ja5n1 . Although the first two reasons are less important these days, I do value my time and don't like to read the same message in multiple lists.

Comment: OT(one)H, I agree that multiple posts to multiple places can be a waste of time.  OT(other)H, this is a chance to show that SO is a superior forum to a list-serv for answering this Q.

Comment: Well, I take it back. Since we all want to increase the popularity of SO (and R!), the more the merrier for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using ggplot2:

```
dnow <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/88561/plain/")
library(ggplot2)
qplot(V1, colour=factor(V2), data=dnow, geom="density")
```

Comment: the link isn't work anymore. This way I can't understadn well what your solution does. Could you fix the link? Thanks...

Comment: @Manoel `qplot(mtcars$drat, colour=factor(mtcars$cyl), data=mtcars, geom="density")` should give you a functional example.

Answer (score 4):

You can also solve this using the lattice package.

```
require(lattice)
dnow <- read.table('http://dpaste.com/88561/plain/')
densityplot(~V1, groups=V2, data=dnow)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using base graphics in a spaghetti code fashion:

```
plot.multi.dens <- function(s)
{
junk.x = NULL
junk.y = NULL
for(i in 1:length(s))
{
junk.x = c(junk.x, density(s[[i]])$x)
junk.y = c(junk.y, density(s[[i]])$y)
}
xr <- range(junk.x)
yr <- range(junk.y)
plot(density(s[[1]]), xlim = xr, ylim = yr, main = "")
for(i in 1:length(s))
{
lines(density(s[[i]]), xlim = xr, ylim = yr, col = i)
}
}
dnow <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/88561/plain/")
library(sqldf)
x <- unlist(sqldf("select V1 from dnow where V2==0"))
y <- unlist(sqldf("select V1 from dnow where V2==1"))
z <- unlist(sqldf("select V1 from dnow where V2==2"))
plot.multi.dens(list(x,y,z))
library(Hmisc)
le <- largest.empty(x,y,.1,.1)
legend(le,legend=c("x","y","z"), col=(1:3), lwd=2, lty = 1)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using sqldf here? It is literally one hundred  times slower than subscripting: x <- with(dnow,V1[V2==0])

Comment: You're right. But I like the sqldf package and approach so I tend to use it in a no-brain fashion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I found myself needing to do this a lot when looking at microarray data, so I rolled this up as part of a library of utility code that I keep on github: [ARE.utils](http://github.com/lianos/ARE.utils/tree/master), specifically the [plot.densities](https://github.com/lianos/ARE.utils/blob/master/R/visuals.R) function.

It uses base graphics so you can take inspiration from that function to create your own, or just take it whole-sale (but it relies on some other functions in that library):

1. [create.densities](https://github.com/lianos/ARE.utils/blob/master/R/datasets.R), which converts a list/matrix/etc of data to a list of densities; and
2. [match.dim](https://github.com/lianos/ARE.utils/blob/master/R/general.R) function (which converts dimension "names" into numeric axes).

(You can, optionally, install the entire package, but I make no promises that I the functions in there won't change in some backwards incompatible way).

It's not hard to write your own such function, but just make sure you have the function pick the correct range on the axes and stuff. Anyway, you would then use the code like this:

```
library(ARE.utils)
# Create a matrix dataset with separate observations in columns
dat <- matrix(c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, mean=3), 
                rnorm(100, mean=3, sd=2)),
              ncol=3)
# Plot them
plot.densities(dat, along='cols')
```

That would create three different density plots on the same axis with their own colors.

Comment: Steve, if this contains useful and passes R CMD check, by all means send it to CRAN.  If it doesn't pass R CMD check yet, work on that part and then go back to the previous step :)

Comment: Dirk, are you implying that backwards compatibility should not be much of a concern?

Comment: Eduardo: What does backwards compatibility have to do with this?  Feel free to email me outside of SO.  I really don't understand your question.

Comment: Dirk: I think he's taking note of my mentioning the possibility of backwards incompatible changes to ARE.utils. I somehow (incorrectly?) expect, like Eduardo, that a package on CRAN would be a bit better maintained/designed than what I have here. Although I do try to design/implement this stuff well, it's not uncommon to find that I've re-implemented something that could be done better with a few commands in base::R and subsequently axe it from the library. Perhaps one day I will submit to CRAN if I feel it's up to snuff, but until then I'm happy to let other people use it for inspiration :-)